# Deleting file after FileReadingMessageSource consumed it

Tags: spring-integration

Is there an option/way in `FileReadingMessageSource` to delete file after running `receive()` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this (xml sample):

```
<int:poller fixed-rate="500">
    <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
</int:poller>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.delete()"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

where that `<poller>` is for `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`

As a `transactionManager` you can use `PseudoTransactionManager`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

In your method for the message handler use ***setDeleteSourceFiles(true)***, see below:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = FILE_CHANNEL_SOURCE, poller = 
@Poller(fixedDelay = INTERVAL))
public MessageSource<File> sourceFiles() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    source.setDirectory(new File(sourceDir));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(FILE_PATTERN));
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = FILE_CHANNEL_SOURCE)
public MessageHandler processedFiles() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(outputDir));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.FAIL);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    return handler;
}
```